# Mounting Samba shares from Ubuntu server to the Desktop

Tags: ubuntu, samba, desktop

I need to mount two Samba shares from my Ubuntu Server to my Desktop they are:

```
[shared]
path = /media/share
read only = no
guest ok = yes

[www]
path = /var/www
read only = no
```

I made two directories in my home folder on the desktop called share and www how do I mount these now? I have to use the terminal btw.

If I run the command: `smbclient -L //192.168.10.101` from my Desktop which is the IP of my server it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount the samba share using a command like:

```
$ mount -t smbfs //192.168.10.101/share /media/share
```

You can check the mount manual for more options. When you get the shares mounted correctly, you can add them to `/etc/fstab` to be mounted after system startup.

Answer (score 1):

Khaled is right, but if you need further info, there's a good old howto in Ubuntuforums:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=280473

The same question was asked on AskUbuntu, and the answers are also very interesting, showing how to make that mount permanent easily

https://askubuntu.com/questions/15312/simple-way-to-create-a-persistent-smb-mount